# How to get a square grid in Chart.js with responsive scatter chart?

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a scatter chart in chart.js where the grid spacing in x will always be equal to the grid spacing in y and the appearance of the grid is truly square, regardless of canvas size or aspect ratio. The chart represents physical space, so I don't want the x and y coordinates to be elongated in either direction or it will appear stretched to the eye.

I'm also looking for a responsive solution since I can't fix the min, max, or grid spacing in either axis as the plotted value ranges change with user input. One thing is for sure though: the canvas size will always be wider than it is tall.

I've tried playing around with grid spacing and aspect ratios but I'm not getting what I need. I was able to get the gridlines truly square only by plotting a dummy point with the y-value at the same magnitude as the maximum x-value, but that essentially just forced the canvas to be square and left too much unused white space at the top.

As an example, the graph might need to be 2000 units wide on the x-axis and 500 units high on the y-axis. Grid spacing would be say, 100 units for both axes. The canvas in this case would be about four times wider than high, but the grid lines should all appear square, rather than rectangular.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since your chart represents physical space, you may be better off using something other than Chart.js, which really isn't made for your use-case.

Comment: To help better answer a question, you need to provide what you tried, errors you got, and docs you looked up. Please consider improving your question. The question ideally should include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scriptable options to calculate the amount of ticks you need with a given spacing to get squares, it need some fine tuning because of rounding but this will give you a rough idea/setup to finetune

Example:

```js
const spacing = 50;

var options = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [{
          x: 0,
          y: 4
        }, {
          x: 2,
          y: 2
        }, {
          x: 4,
          y: 0
        }],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          x: 2,
          y: 3
        }, {
          x: 6,
          y: 8
        }, {
          x: 0,
          y: 3
        }],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          count: (ctx) => {
            const {
              scale: {
                maxHeight
              }
            } = ctx;

            return maxHeight / spacing;
          }
        }
      },
      x: {
        ticks: {
          count: (ctx) => {
            const {
              scale: {
                maxWidth
              }
            } = ctx;

            return maxWidth / spacing;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll play around with it and see if I can make it work with my data set.